# How to split a multistring in python?

Tags: python

Given a multistring returned by a function I'm accessing using ctypes of the form:

```
"the quick brown fox\x00jumped over the lazy\00programmer\00\00"
```

What's the best way to turn this into a python list like this:

```
["the quick brown fox", "jumped over the lazy", "programmer"]
```

I tried using foo.split('\x00'), but that did not work.

Comment: This is really odd. Using raw strings doesn't help, btw, which is why this beats me.

Comment: `foo.split()` returns a new string and does not modify `foo`, so you may need to write `foo=foo.split('\x00')`

Comment: What do you want out of `"\0foo\0\0bar\0\0"` ? Do two of `\0` together terminate the multistring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using filter would be an elegant way to solve this.

```
>>> s = "the quick brown fox\x00jumped over the lazy\00programmer\00\00"  
>>> filter(None, s.split('\x00'))  
['the quick brown fox', 'jumped over the lazy', 'programmer']
```

Comment: What's the trick to adding a code snippet and having it formatted correctly?  I used the "add code here" button but it still didn't work.

Comment: @musicfreak: thanks... yet another wiki syntax I need to learn :(

Comment: To use the 'code' button, type in the code, select it and then press the button.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions - several of them worked, but the filter() version is the one that got checked in.

I think the fact I am using ctypes complicates things. This is a string buffer returned by a call to <some outside library>:

Comment: <insert brief frustrating delay with the system whining about 5 minutes or something...>

    s = create_string_buffer(length)
    <call to library, using s in lieu of char *>
    foo = s[0:length]
    return filter(None, foo.split('\x00'))

Trying to use s or s.value directly always seemed to get truncated at the first NULL <which I think may have been the heart of my problem> - assigning to foo seems like a kludge to me, but a kludge that works is better than nothing, I guess. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Given

```
sentence = "the quick brown fox\x00jumped over the lazy\00programmer\00\00"
[phrase for phrase in sentence.split("\x00") if phrase != ""]
```

---

**EDIT**
Straight from the horse's mouth:

```
>>> sentence = "the quick brown fox\x00jumped over the lazy\00programmer\00\00"
>>> [phrase for phrase in sentence.split('\x00') if phrase != ""]
['the quick brown fox', 'jumped over the lazy', 'programmer']

Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  9 2009, 14:20:26)
```

Comment: In this case, simply "if phrase" will work, as strings are True iff nonempty.

Comment: True.  Just being verbose for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = "the quick brown fox\x00jumped over the lazy\00programmer\00\00"
>>> s.strip('\x00').split('\x00')
['the quick brown fox', 'jumped over the lazy', 'programmer']
```